# iOS app needs reinstall to receive push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have encountered a strange behaviour with an iOS app that my team has developed.

The users can enable notifications in the app and receives notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging. We had complaints that the notifications were not coming through, so after some basic troubleshooting, we discovered the only solution was for the users to uninstall the app and reinstall it while allowing the notifications when they start it the first time.

Why did this happen? Did something change from Apple's side? Publishing a new version of the app fixes the problem?

Thanks

Comment: We are facing the same problem, publishing of new version didn't work for us unfortunately